# How to Search Items in ComboBox in Windows Phone 8.1 App?

Tags: c#, search, windows-phone-8, combobox, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing windows phone app.In my combobox so many  items are there.Now I want to search item in combobox.whenever I click combobox, items are displayed but not show any search textbox.

```
<Button x:Name="btn1"  Content="submit"  Click="btn1_Click"></Button>
        <Popup x:Name= "Pop" IsOpen="False">
            <Grid>
  <TextBox x:Name= "SearchText box"/>
                <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="399" Margin="0,0,-348,-524" x:Name="Listbox1">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding yourdata}"></TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
        </Popup>
```

Actually what happend is in my combobox having somany cities names,now I want to perticuler city name.how to get perticular city name,how to search.pllease hellp me.
in  my code page

```
      public async void getdata()
                {
                    var client = new NewReloadApp.JsonWebClient();

                    var resp1 = await client.DoRequestAsync(Url.weburl + "getRechargeCircleList");

                    string result1 = resp1.ReadToEnd();
                    JArray jsonArray = JArray.Parse(result1);

                    for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.Count; j++)
                    {
                        JObject jobj = (JObject)jsonArray[j];

                        string id = (string)jobj["CircleID"];
                        string statename = (string)jobj["CircleName"];

                                 listbox1.items.add(statename );
}
    }
```

but listbox1 not shown

Comment: try ading `IsEditable="true"` to your combobox

Comment: @ShaminderSAujla IsEditable not  shown in my code

Answer (score 1):

Combobox does not allow to search from ComboboxItem

Please use another control to search functionality or create your own control like using Popup controll and put Listbox in it and bind your data. then add search textbox & search from listbox

Comment: please suggest what kind of control I take?

Comment: @AnilKumar you can open Popup Control on click event. then put list box in it and bind your data. Also put one Textbox to search data from listbox.. it will be like custome combobox with search box

Comment: popup control means like popup

Comment: Thank you for your response.I will try and tell you

Comment: I have small doubt. which control i used for click event

Comment: you can use button for click event

Comment: <Popup name= “Pop">
 <Grid>
  <Textbox name= “SearchText box"/>
  <Listbox>
   <Listbox.itemtemplets>
    <Datatemplet>
     <textblock text={Binding your data}
    </Datatemplet>
   </Listbox.itemtemplets>
  </Listbox>
 </Grid>
< /Popup>


Now open popup on click event like

if (!Pop.isopen)
{
 Pop.isopen = true
 }

Comment: but how to bind data to listbox.listbox id not shown in my code page

Comment: Create one class of your json data  then Iterate your json data in thet class and then bind to listbox..